# Laravel: Comment with the highest number of likes. How to change background color?

Tags: laravel

Every post has many comments. Common situation. I want to get a comment with the highest post like and change class in this commnet for example, style="background: red".

How to do it? 
THx

Comment: Does your comment model has an attribute `likes` or something. Or is a like a separate model?

Comment: Also, how do you render the data in your view?

Comment: Good question. Likes is separatly model. I can imagine: $post->comments->orderBy('like', 'desc)->take(1)->get(); but this is primitive solution.